# Did Isuzu have a crush on (or was in love with) Hiroshi, or was it just the scent?

Tags: ookami-kakushi

It has been some time since I watched the anime (and I do not have access to it at the moment), but I recently saw an episode 1 excerpt on YouTube where the main characters are in the playground, and I couldn't remember if Isuzu really liked Hiroshi or it was just the wolf-scent thing.

I do remember they end up as "just friends"...

But did she really had feelings for him?